# How to pass livewire entanglement into Alpine component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a modal component which uses Alpine, which I made into a Blade component.

```
// Modal blade component
<div x-data="{ open = false }">
  <div x-show="open"></div>
</div>
```

I want to share the `open` state with a Livewire component, but I don't know how to pass the `@entangle` directive through the component:

```
// Livewire component
<x-modal>
</x-modal>
```

---

I tried this:

```
// Modal Blade component
<div {{ $attributes }}>
  <div x-show="open"></div>
</div>

// Livewire component
<div x-data="{ open = @entangle('livewire-state')}">
  <div x-show="open"></div>
</div>
```

But the `entangle` directive just get parsed into string.

Answer (score 1):

Your `x-data` object isn't properly syntaxed. You are using a `=` instead of a `:`. You should be seeing a console error also, if you happened to have the console open. Use the following syntax:

```html
<div x-data="{ open: @entangle('livewire-state')}">
```

Read more on `@entangle` in the [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#sharing-state).